# Flutter Android Alarm Manager: missing implementation

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

So I've been looking through thousands of StackOverflow questions and reading documentations of flutter's android_alarm_manager plugin. Eventually, I couldn't get It to work. When I tried to use a plugin in my code it throws an "Implementation not found/Missing implementation" error. I tried everything I found on the internet but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package novy.vip.novynaplo
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

And here is my dart code that is called by the alarm manager:

```
void backgroundFetch() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  print(prefs.getString("someStringIneed"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a week reading after the issue, I found how to solve my issue:

**Solution**

It looks like that my kotlin code was deprecated and it didn't register my plugins like it should have, so I changed it to this one:

```
package novy.vip.novynaplo

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }
}
```

And for most people that would have solved the issue but I also had to add this snipet to my **AndroidManifest.xml** (inside of `<activity></activity>`):

```
<meta-data
   android:name="flutterEmbedding"
   android:value="2"/>
```